# Prometheus is continuously using more memory

Tags: kubernetes, memory, prometheus

I am using Prometheus v2.41.0 installed via the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) helm chart with the following values:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    retention: 30d
    retentionSize: 49GiB
    storageSpec:
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 50Gi
```

Letting it run for a few days I get this memory graph:
[Memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffIsw.png)

It keeps rising and does not seem to stop. What are the configurations to limit this since I don't think everything needs to be in memory all the time.

At the same time the PVC storage looks like this, which is more expected, at double the size of the memory usage:
[PVC usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWrYN.png)

Here is the pprof heap data:

```
Fetching profile over HTTP from http://localhost:55947/debug/pprof/heap
File: prometheus
Type: inuse_space
Time: Jun 12, 2023 at 2:54pm (CEST)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 216MB, 69.80% of 309.47MB total
Dropped 147 nodes (cum <= 1.55MB)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 135
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
   58.55MB 18.92% 18.92%    58.55MB 18.92%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/model/labels.(*Builder).Labels
   39.97MB 12.92% 31.84%    39.97MB 12.92%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/scrape.newScrapePool.func1
   24.51MB  7.92% 39.76%    24.51MB  7.92%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/model/textparse.(*PromParser).Metric
      23MB  7.43% 47.19%       31MB 10.02%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tsdb.newMemSeries
   17.50MB  5.66% 52.84%    17.50MB  5.66%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tsdb/chunkenc.NewXORChunk
   12.50MB  4.04% 56.88%    18.02MB  5.82%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tsdb.(*memSeries).mmapCurrentHeadChunk
   11.83MB  3.82% 60.71%    11.83MB  3.82%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/scrape.(*scrapeCache).trackStaleness
   10.51MB  3.39% 64.10%    10.51MB  3.39%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tsdb/chunkenc.(*bstream).writeByte
    8.84MB  2.86% 66.96%     8.84MB  2.86%  github.com/prometheus/prometheus/scrape.(*scrapeCache).addRef
    8.79MB  2.84% 69.80%     8.79MB  2.84%  github.com/golang/snappy.Encode
```

This is also confusing since it states that it is only using 309MB of memory, compared to the 3-4GB it is actually using.

Finally here is the TSDB data:
[TSDB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6990M.png)

So is this how Prometheus is expected to behave or is there any way to limit the amount of memory it needs?

Thanks

I tried looking for people with similar problems but they didn't give fitting answers

Answer (score 0):

See if the following link will help you in finding the cuase of the memory usage
you will need to run the tools described on this page as the root cause is probably how may labels you have in memory.

https://source.coveo.com/2021/03/03/prometheus-memory/

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I am familiar with that site. It recommends to drop the id label which I would like to do. It however does not explain how to do that at all.
Also to my understanding that would only lessen the problem as the memory would still rise, only slower. So there should still be a solution to limit the memory usage / mmap size.
Also according to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/WjjWMAbLcK8) dropping the id table can cause unforeseen problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).